# What exactly happens to function argument availability when using a filter?

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks

The goal of this question is:

- to be able to interpret WP docs better
- to understand what's exactly happening in this scenario
- to verify what I'm thinking is correct

---

I came across this code.

```
    function register() {
        ...
        add_filter( "plugin_action_links_$this->plugin", array( $this, 'settings_link' ) );
    }

    public function settings_link($links) {
        $settings_link = '<a href="admin.php?page=alecaddd_plugin">Settings</a>';
        array_push( $links, $settings_link );
        return $links;
    }
```

When I debug `settings_link($links)`, I see $links is an array with a 'deactivate' key and value.

Looking at [wp dev docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_action_links_plugin_file/), it seems `$links` relates to the $actions parameter.
`apply_filters( "plugin_action_links_{$plugin_file}", string[] $actions, string $plugin_file, array $plugin_data, string $context )`

I noticed though, that the other parameters, `$plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context`, were not available in the debugger.

I then changed the code as follows.

```
        function register() {
            ...
            add_filter( "plugin_action_links_$this->plugin", array( $this, 'settings_link' ), 10, 4 ); );  // change 1
        }

        public function settings_link($links, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context ) {  // change 2
        $settings_link = '<a href="admin.php?page=alecaddd_plugin">Settings</a>';
            array_push( $links, $settings_link );
            return $links;
        }
```

Low and behold, now the other parameters `$plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context` are now available in my function.

I suspect calling `add_filter` while only passing a callback, is some form of workflow to make things faster & easier.

Can somebody clarify further, or just confirming, what's exactly happening here?
Is this behavior documented somewhere in the official docs?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Before you had `add_filter('..', [..], 10, 1)` (because 10 and 1 are the defaults), now you have `add_filter('..', [..], 10, 4)`. With the `4` you instruct WP to pass 4 arguments to this method. And yes, `add_filter` and `add_action` basically allow you to change somebody else's behaviour. Otherwise you'd have to override their code, which would get undone by an update.

Comment: @kero that's the missing piece of information I needed. I didn't know the default value for the number of arguments was 1. That explains everything. I could have known from the add_filter docs.. anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to note is that action and filter hooks are mostly just standard PHP callback behaviour.

The second argument passed to `add_filter()` should be a PHP [Callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). When the filter is applied with [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/), that callback is just run through the core PHP function [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Any additional arguments to `apply_filters()` are then passed as `$args` to your callback.

The WordPress specific behaviour is around defining the number of arguments your callback accepts. When you add a filter with `add_filter()`, the 4th argument defines the number of arguments that the callback accepts. WordPress then only passes that number of arguments when it calls `call_user_func_array()`.

Normally passing more arguments than a callback accepts is perfectly fine. The exception is built-in PHP functions, which will throw an error. For example, this will throw an error:

```
call_user_func_array( 'addslashes', array( 'argument one', 'argument two' ) );
```

To prevent this WordPress makes you declare how many arguments your callback accepts, and trims the number passed to `call_user_func_array()` accordingly.

There is an old ticket about deprecating this behaviour [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14671), and you can follow the discussion to see why that never happened. The short version is performance and backwards compatibility.

Comment: Indeed, as @kero pointed cleared up in the comments. This was a really noobish from my part but I needed it cleared regardless. Thank you.